# MS Access VBA DoCmd.ApplyFilter IsNull() evaluating false

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm writing some VBA to create a search page in my MS Acccess database and running into some trouble with `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` in the `Search_Click()` sub.

[image]
My code looks like this

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", _
    "([site] = [Forms]![SWP Search]![txtSite] " & _
          " Or IsNull([Forms]![SWP Search]![txtSite])) " & _
    "AND " & _
    "([asset] = [Forms]![SWP Search]![txtAsset] " & _
        " Or IsNull([Forms]![SWP Search]![txtAsset]))"
End Sub
```

Or in pseudo code...

```
 Shows results where true...
([site column] = txtbox1 OR isnull(txtbox1)) 
AND 
([asset col  ] = txtbox2 OR isnull(txtbox2))
```

Obviously, the desired functionality is as follows...

1. Site chosen, Asset blank -> Filter on site only
2. Site chosen, Asset chosen -> Filter on both
3. Site blank, Asset blank -> Return all rows
4. Site blank, Asset chosen -> Filter on asset only

But what's actually happening is...

1. Site chosen, Asset blank -> works
2. Site chosen, Asset chosen -> works
3. Site blank, Asset blank -> *no rows returned*
4. Site blank, Asset chosen -> *no rows returned*

So it seems like when Site is blank, IsNull() isn't evaluating true and so the first part of the filter is FALSE and the thing just quits there and then.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try does using `IsEmpty()` instead of `IsNull()` make difference, ie

```
      "(IsEmpty([Forms]![SWP Search]![txtSite]) " & _
      " Or [site] Like [Forms]![SWP Search]![txtSite] )" & _
"AND" & _
    "( IsEmpty([Forms]![SWP Search]![txtAsset])" & _
    " Or [asset] Like [Forms]![SWP Search]![txtAsset] )"
```

as the empty txtbox might return empty string, not NULL as you expect. Or compare textbox value against empty string, possibly using `trim()` first.

Comment: IsEmpty() applies only to variables of type Variant.

Comment: It turns out that I had a set default value of `""` for the combo boxes. I thought that would mean NULL, but apparently it doesn't. I checked in the debugger and `IsNull()` wasn't evaluating as true when empty. So I got rid of default value and `IsNull()` worked great. Problem solved!

Comment: If you want the default value to be Null, set the default value property to "Null" (without the quotes).